# If $g(x+1)+g(x-1)≥g(x)$ and $g(x)=f(x)-x$ then find the minimum value of $I=\int_1^{25}f(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

**Question**

It is given as a part of the question, that for all x,
$$f(x-1)+f(x+1)≥ f(x)+x$$
where f is a real and continuous function

and,
$$g(x)=f(x)-x$$

Upon using the above inequalities we get,
$$g(x+1)+g(x-1)≥g(x)$$

The question is to find the minimum value of
$$I=\int_1^{25}f(x)dx$$

**What I tried**

I substituted $f(x)=g(x)+x$ using the equation provided in the question.

So
$$I=\int_1^{25}f(x)dx = \int_1^{25} g(x)dx +\int_1^{25} xdx$$
So $$I=(\int_1^{25} g(x)dx)  +312$$

So the minimum value of I is 324 + minimum value of $I=(\int_1^{25} g(x)dx)$

I know that the minimum value of $I=(\int_1^{25} g(x)dx)$ is 0, because the textbook answer to this question is 312

I would like some help on how we can prove that the minimum value of $I=(\int_1^{25} g(x)dx)$ is $0$ using the given conditions.

Thanks in advance!

Regards

Comment: hint try to prove thar g(x)+g(x+3)$\ge$0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $g(x) = g(x-1) - g(x-2) + \epsilon(x)$, with $\epsilon(x)$ being a function of $x$ such that $\epsilon(x)\ge 0$. Then $$g(x+1) = - g(x-2) + \epsilon(x) + \epsilon(x+1)$$ $$g(x+2) = -g(x-1) + \epsilon(x+1) + \epsilon(x+2)$$ $$g(x+3) = -g(x) + \epsilon(x+2) +\epsilon(x+3)$$

In general, it can be proven that $$g(x) = -g(x-3) + \epsilon(x-1) + \epsilon(x)$$

Therefore to minimize $$\int_1^{25}g(x) dx$$

$\epsilon(x)$ must equal $0$ for all $x$. Then, the recurrence is $g(x) = -g(x-3)$. If we then split the integral into intervals of $3$, it becomes $$\int_1^4 g(x) dx + \int_4^7 g(x) dx + ... \int_{22}^{25} g(x) dx$$

But because $g(x) = -g(x-3)$, every $2$ integrals cancel out. Therefore, $$\min\int_1^{25}g(x) dx = 0$$

and $$\min\int_1^{25}f(x) dx = 312$$

Comment: Thanks! That was really helpful

Comment: No problem - glad I was able to help!